# Python Webscraping: Need help acquiring data-value from span html tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am currently trying to grab the data-test value of rounded dollars but I keep getting error NoneType and im just wondering how to solve this thanks :D
[Snippet of website html code of the part i want to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euc4n.png)

Here is my current code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.priceline.com/m/fly/search/YYZ-YUL-20200214/?cabin-class=ECO&no-date-search=false&search-type=11&num-adults=1&refclickid=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find('span', attrs={'data-test': 'rounded-dollars'})
print(price)
```

Comment: The data might be injected via Javascript, so BeautifulSoup doesn't see anything. Could you share the URL?

Comment: What happens when you use:  
```for i in find_all('span'):
  print(i)
```

Comment: @AndrejKesely 
here is the link:

https://www.priceline.com/m/fly/search/YYZ-YUL-20200214/?cabin-class=ECO&no-date-search=false&search-type=11&num-adults=1&refclickid=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F 

I am trying to scrape the first price listed which is the cheapest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need selenium to get the exact value(s) shown on the page, because data of this page filled dynamically using `Javascript` from `JSON`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"***YOUR_CHROME-DRIVER_PATH***", chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.priceline.com/m/fly/search/YYZ-YUL-20200214/?cabin-class=ECO&no-date-search=false&search-type=11&num-adults=1&refclickid=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F')

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
price = soup.find_all('span', {'data-test': 'rounded-dollars'})
for price in prices: print(price.text, end=' | ')
```

Output:

```
112 | 112 | 112 | 112 | 112 | 112
```

Comment: When using Selenium, is there a way where Selenium does not open instances of chrome browsers to the URL to acquire the data.
Seems to take quite a while since i want to loop and grab like 10 days consecutively and using Selenium, it opens an instance each time and takes longer and longer to load and scrape  as the range increases

Comment: @s4phan Check my edits, it will not open the browser. but still it will take time and memory. For better performance you have to use `requests` to scrape this page.